How to Implement Speech-to-Text in Android TV Programmatically with Kotlin (Without Using SearchFragment)
I am working on an Android TV application where I want to implement speech-to-text functionality. I would like to achieve this with a button. When the user clicks this button, it should open the speech-to-text interface from any OS (e.g., Alexa, Android, Google). After the user speaks, I need to capture and process the spoken text.
I've attempted to use RecognizerIntent but haven't had success. Can someone guide me on how to implement this feature in an Android TV app?
Details:

The application is being developed in Kotlin.
I prefer not to use SearchFragment.
I need the solution to work with Android TV devices.

Any suggestions or sample code would be greatly appreciated!
